# Does The Man-Kzin Wars series have any specific reading order?

Tags: larry-niven, man-kzin-wars, baen

Is there any specific order in which The Man-Kzin Wars series should be read in order to avoid missing any vital information that is taken for granted in later volumes?

Comment: Given that you're evidently aware that Baen [collected them](https://booksreadingorder.com/larry-niven/) is there a special reason you think that you shouldnt start at book one and finish at [book twenty-five](https://booksreadingorder.com/man-kzin-wars-xv/)?

Comment: @Valorum It's an open universe with many authors contributing short stories, as far as I know. Given that circumstance, it's not self-evident that the story of this universe is narrated in a chronological manner. Instead, I consider it likely thar authors come up with any kind of story set in that universe and Baen giving their okay, if they like it. For example, there is this "Treasure Planet" book, and if I am in the mood for that kind of story, does it work as a stand-alone experience, or do I have to read all other (or some essential) volumes published before that?

Comment: Just a comment that (in-universe) "chronological order" ≠ "in order to avoid missing any vital information that is taken for granted in later volumes?" Publication order is usually much closer to the latter. (E.g., prequels often assume knowledge from the original story arc, etc.)

Comment: @Valorum You mean book fifteen, which is what your link goes to.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/review/R3VM08184830VE

Comment: The order in which they were published is essentially the order in which they were written, so it’s not possible for an earlier book to have stories where you need to know something from a later book, because that would be impossible at the time of publishing. So again; why not just read them in order?